# Why is 才 correct but 还 not in 我才27岁?

Tags: word-choice

This is the conversation my friend and I had:

> X：你多大年纪
>
> I：我还27岁
>
> X：还？
>
> I：27岁是1990年出生的，跟你同一的90后
>
> X：那应该说，我才27岁

I was going to make an impression that I'm *only* 27, which implies that I'm not so old yet, even from her stardard. But she said 还 is not the correct word and I should use 才 here.

还 has the meaning such as "still" or "yet".

Why is 还 not correct in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you are trying to say "I'm still 27.", "还" does not work in this context, since it is only used to imply *an action is still ongoing* or *something still exists*. Grammatically speaking, it should be used before a verb, not a noun.

On the other hand, "才" in this context is used to emphasize *a (merely) small quantity*. Therefore, it should be put before a noun. There are other usage of "才", making it can be put before a verb, but that's a different case.

Maybe this example will help you to notice the usage of "还" and "才" (example from [Chinese Grammar Wiki](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Using_%22cai%22_for_small_numbers)).

> 你**才**一百斤，**还**要减肥？

Comment: or before an adjective, e.g. 我还年轻

Answer (score 3):

> *还 has the meaning such as "still" or "yet"*.
>
> *Why is 还 not correct in this situation?*

- For 还 to mean "still" you need to use it before a verb like 是 (is / be)

Example: "我的生日是明天，所以凌晨前我**還是** (is still) 二十七歲"

- For  还 to mean "yet" you need to use it with 未 and before a verb

Example: "我**还未**到二十七歲" , "我**还未**滿廿七歲" or  "我**还未**足二十七歲" (all mean I am not 27 yet)

"我才廿七歲" = "I am only 27" implies it is a young age from your point of view. It is in fact short for "我才(只有-only)二十七歲"

The simplest answer to the question "你多大年纪?" is "我今年二十七歲" or simply "我廿七歲" This answer already indicated you are currently 27, which mean you are still 27, not 28 yet

Edit:

> *I was going to imply is not if I'm (still) 27 or 28 but if I'm also as young as the friend.*

It would be "我也祇是二十七歲"

[我也 (I too)] [祇是 (is only)]  [二十七歲 (27 years old)]

No matter your friend is 21 years or 30 years young, the above statement implies you are also young at the age of 27

Comment: 廿 is, basically, never used in Mandarin like this.

Comment: Change it to 二十七歲 then

Comment: Thanks but what I was going to imply is not if I'm (still) 27 or 28 but if I'm also as young as the friend.

Comment: See my edit at the bottom of my post.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody says "我还27岁", but you can say "我还 ‘不到’ 27岁 "(I am not 27 yet)."我还 ‘不到’ 21岁, 我不能喝酒 "
"我还未到二十七歲"  is way to formal.